# NullPointerException on .equals()

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I have a problem on my `if` statement.

Here is my code.

```
public class WiFiService extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context mcontext;
SharedPreferences prefs = null;
Boolean flagIsConnected = false;
String homeBSSID = "null";
String bssid = "null";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context mcontext, Intent intent) {
    NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

    if(info != null) {

        if(info.isConnected() && !flagIsConnected) {
            //state change from disconnected to connected
            flagIsConnected = true; // set flag here to
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)mcontext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

            Log.d("WifiConnection", "Connected");
            this.mcontext = mcontext;

            Wifi();
        }else if(!info.isConnected() && flagIsConnected){
            //state change from connect to disconnected
            flagIsConnected = false;
        }
    }
}

private void Wifi() {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)mcontext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

    prefs = mcontext.getSharedPreferences("com.bedrock.live", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    bssid = wifiInfo.getBSSID();
    homeBSSID = prefs.getString("homeBSSID", "null");

    if (bssid.equals(homeBSSID) == true){
        Log.d("WifiConnection", "Home.");
    }
    else
        Log.d("WifiConnection", "Null.");

    Log.d("WifiConnection", "HomeWifi");
    }
}
```

when I run this and turn off the wifi, it crashes and shows me this;

```
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.bedrock.live, PID: 3127
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.bedrock.live.service.WiFiService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2601)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5238)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:931)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bedrock.live.service.WiFiService.Wifi(WiFiService.java:52)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bedrock.live.service.WiFiService.onReceive(WiFiService.java:35)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2594)
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370) 
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5238) 
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:931) 
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-02 18:16:43.269 3127-3127/com.bedrock.live E/AndroidRuntime:     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
```

as you can see, my code is supposed to get saved string from `SharedPreferences` and log "home" when it matches, and log "null" when it doesnt matches.

I have no ideas.. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`

Comment: homeBSSID cannot be null. So I suggest you to switch your if condition: 

    if (homeBSSID.equals(bssid) == true){

Comment: i think your bssid is null, not your homeBSSID

Comment: @StefanBeike thanks for fast answering! It really helped! Thanks ;)